# How do I create a userstyle for Google Chrome and the Google Tasks website?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, userscripts, stylish

I want to create a *Stylish* script, for Google Chrome that will change the notes `<textarea>` size on [the Google Tasks page](https://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas?pli=1).

The element I want to style is:

```
<textarea id=":2.notes-editor" class="l lc" rows="5" style=""></textarea>
```

Currently my *Stylish* script looks like this.

```
#2.notes-editor{
height:100px;

}

url: https://mail.google.com
```

For some reason it is not working.

Comment: Chrome provides lousy support for iframes that don't have an https? `src`.  So, currently, Stylish does not work on such frames and it's more than a pain to try and script for them.  You'll need to write an extension or userscript (not Stylish script), that recursively handles iframes.  The node you want is a couple iframes deep.   I might post an answer showing how to do this, if I feel frisky.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try forcing it with `!important`?

```
#2.notes-editor{
    height:100px !important;
}
```

If this doesn't work, maybe its because the `textarea` is inside an `iframe` (I've [read](http://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/15032/how-to-apply-css-to-content-within-an-iframe/p1) that the css styling inside an iframe on Chrome isn't working as expected).

Comment: Then the problem might be due to the iframe.
Try using that userstyle without a domain restriction and see if that forces the iframe to render it. Or maybe get the iframe reference link and include that url in the userstyle as well.

Comment: it may be an iframe issue. not sure

Comment: Also, i just noticed that the id of the textarea is `:2.task-editor`. Have you tried using the classes instead? Something like `textarea.l.H { }`

Comment: ya i tried with the classes and it also doesnt work, and i tried with the     `:2.notes-editor` and it doesnt work. this website has a [discussion about this iframe issue.](http://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/33441/tinymce-and-chromefirefox-differences)